# Using template in Django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I'm on Chapter 4: Templates of the Django tutorial, and I'm trying to run the following in an Emacs inferior mode using Python:

```
>>> from django import template
>>> t = template.Template('My name is {{ name }}.')
>>> c = template.Context({'name': 'Adrian'})
>>> print t.render(c)
My name is Adrian.
>>> c = template.Context({'name': 'Fred'})
>>> print t.render(c)
My name is Fred.
```

But I get the error [here](http://pastebin.com/uVuTLUj2).

A quick search suggests that I should do be setting my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE like so:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "settings.py"
```

However, I run into this error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings.py
```

I'm using Fedora 16. How do I correctly resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the `python manage.py shell`, since that would have `settings.py` in `.` directory.

### Otherwise:

Consider `settings.py` just another python library and you need to ensure its added to `sys.path` and then you can do as follows :

```
import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ

setup_environ(settings)  # Setting up the env settings
```

This sets up the settings to your environment. **[ This is the right way ]**

There is no secret recipe in `settings.py` and since django in itself is a library to python, so it could not be default set any paths to your `sys.path` unless imported and executed - as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use `setup_environ` as suggested in another answer.

A hint regarding this specific exception: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is a Python module name, so it may not end with ".py". Usually, this would be `your_django_site.settings` and the module/directory `your_django_site` has to be in `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

All Django code not in a project should either be run from the Django REPL, available via `./manage.py shell`, or run as a [standalone script](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to test anything in the shell for Django, you should use the Django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

This will start up a Python interpreter which will magically have your settings file (and the rest of your project) on the Python path.

(This assumes you have a project already. If not, use `django-admin.py startproject my_project_name`.)